# ODIN configuration file - elements' meanings

Tags: samsung, odin

I started this question in order to have more light shed on a tool that's used by almost all the Samsung device owners that perform operations such as flashing: **ODIN**.

Since there's already a good answer that covers the meaning behind the most commonly used checkboxes, I would like to make everyone think about the ODIN configuration file, namely **Odin3.ini**. This file resides in the same position as the ODIN main executable, and it's mandatory in order to run the program itself. Its content (v.3.10.7) can be observed below:

```
[Option]
Title=odin
FactoryResetTime=1
OptionEnable=1
SLP=0
AuthorityKey=pw
RtnForSprint=1


[APOption]
RePartition=0
AutoReboot=1
FResetTime=1
FlashLock=0
TFlash=0
NandErase=0


[CPOption]
PhoneEFSClear=0
PhoneBootUpdate=0k

[UIOption]
LED=0


[ButtonOption]
Bootloader=1
PDA=1
Phone=1
CSC=1
UMS/PATCH=0
USERDATA=0

[D300Jig]
;[0] not use / COM [1~2] usable
D300COM=0
;[0] not use / [1] use
MicroCable=0

[PortArrange]
;SAMSUNG Mobile Modem port (for Download mode)
DPort0=
DPort1= 
DPort2=
DPort3= 
DPort4= 
DPort5=
DPort6=
DPort7=
;SAMSUNG Android USB Modem port (for Samsung Kies)
SPort0=
SPort1=
SPort2=
SPort3=
SPort4=
SPort5=
SPort6=
SPort7=
```

As of recently, I performed some tests on the abovementioned values. You can see my findings in the answer below, which is freely editable by anyone.

Now comes the question part: was anyone able to ascertain the usage of those settings I was unable to/didn't test? For instance:

- Usefulness of `FactoryResetTime` - it doesn't reset the flash counter, before you say that;
- FTP connection output after editing `SLP`;
- Eventual output of **DeviceInfo**;
- Usage of `AuthorityKey`;
- Usage of `RtnForSprint` (only v3.10.7);
- Usage of the **T Flash** checkbox;
- What's supposed to be chosen as **UMS/PATCH** file - I've never seen one.

And yes, I'm aware that this is a bit of work, it's broad, and that it's not strictly related to Android. However, I found nothing on the XDA community, and I feel that we've yet to discover the real power of this ODIN tool. Any answer about this topic has the potential to help Samsung users out there to better understand this piece of software.

Comment: UMS/PATCH might be for flashing a partial update rather than simply overwriting everything.  USERDATA is almost certainly `/data`.  I'm guessing most of the rest is really only useful on Samsung's intranet.

Comment: @MatthewRead As of now, I started disassembling Odin's code. The interesting thing, is that I found the "LOKE" component to be referenced in a string. I guess that it's for the purpose of output. Regarding the USERDATA, I experienced internal SD wiping anytime I flashed a stock ROM. Maybe that's made to prevent Odin from cleaning the /storage/sdcard0 (/data/media).

Comment: I think that I've found the IP of the server Odin connects to. It appears to be **165.213.149.206**.

Comment: Found a new flag that can be manually added, in order to make **Phone EFS Clear** and **Phone Bootloader Update** selectable. It belongs to the **[Options]** label.

Comment: You might want to move all of that into an answer.  Possibly make it Community Wiki if you want others to be able to update it.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'll do it as soon as possible. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @MatthewRead, this answer will reflect the same fashion of the question - it will be editable by anyone who has something useful to say.

In regards to the original question, here are my latest findings:

- **For label `[Options]`:**

  - `Title`: string. Used for changing the string displayed near "Odin"; freely customizable;
  - `FactoryResetTime`: unknown. I was able to change this value, but nothing happened;
  - `OptionEnable`: flag. When set to `0`, it makes any setting greyed out;
  - `PhoneEnable`: flag. Usually not present in a fresh Odin3.ini, can be manually added. When set to `1`, it makes **Phone EFS Clear** and **Phone Bootloader Update** selectable;
  - `DeviceInfo`: flag. Usually not present in a fresh Odin3.ini, can be manually added. When set to `1`, it makes the **DeviceInfo** checkbox available. Ticking the checkbox doesn't produce any result;
  - `SLP`: flag. When set to `1`, makes the program try a connection to **165.213.149.206** via FTP, in order to search for updates of the main executable. NOTE: I backtracked the IP, and it indeedly is a Korean server;
  - `AuthorityKey`: unknown. This seems like a string of some kind, and I think it's connected to the previous parameter, but I've no clues;
  - `RtnForSprint`: flag. Untested.
- **For label `[APOption]`:**

  - From `RePartition` to `NandErase`: flags. Editing them modifies the default behaviour of the corresponding option (`0` = unticked / `1` = ticked).
- **For label `[CPOption]`:**

  - `PhoneEFSClear`: flag. Usually, the corresponding checkbox is greyed out. By changing the value to `1`, it's possible to make it be checked, but still greyed out. Doing so will make the application prompt you to choose a firmware file, preventing you to start the flashing process only for, say, rebooting;
  - `PhoneBootUpdate`: apparently flag. The default value of `0k` may seem odd, but this flag does the same thing as the previous one, on the **Phone Bootloader Update** checkbox.
- **For label `[UIOption]`:**

  - `LED`: unknown. It may be anything: I changed this value, but nothing happened.
- **For label `[ButtonOption]`:**

  - From `Bootloader` to `UMS/PATCH`: flags. Editing them enables or "greyes" out the corresponding checkbox (`0` = disabled / `1` = enabled);
  - `USERDATA`: unknown, possibly flag. Since I didn't find any reference for this value in the program's code, I guess that this is a feature that will be developed in the future. For now, it does nothing.
- **For label `[D300Jig]`:**

  - `D300COM`: integer. I changed this value, but nothing happened;
  - `MicroCable`: flag. I changed this value, but nothing happened.
- **For label `[PortArrange]`:**

  - From `DPort0` to `SPort7`: unknown. Untested.

**Notes:**

- **`SLP`:** as previously mentioned, this flag triggers a FTP connection to a hard-coded IP address. I think that it may be useful in order to update Odin from a trusted source, but I've no proof. ***It would be useful if someone with an outdated Odin tests this***;
- **`D300Jig`:** I found a reference to this section in Odin's code, along with a string that's supposed to be displayed at output. Still, I wasn't able to make it work. Two Russian forums claim it to be a way to flash firmwares on old devices wo/ neither Loke nor the Recovery partition. More research is needed.

Comment: It may be unrelated to this topic, but previous versions of Odin (v3.7) did have a "Dump" option. There's no way to manually turn it on, and after a discussion with the author of Heimdall, Benjamin Dobell, I can confirm that it's Loke that signals the feature's availability to Odin. The later versions of the software lack the feature, since the latest bootloaders do not implement it either.

Answer (score 2):

I just reverse engineered the Odin3 ini part (using IDA 66 + HexRaysDecompiler & Rohitab API Monitor 2.32).

So these are all available **ini settings** + it's **default values**:

```
; These ini settings applies to Odin3 v3.12 (Compiled 21. jan 2016)

[Option]
 ; [Avoid missing this or anything starting like 'Odin3. [Android + SLP]' ]
    Title                   =       [Android + SLP]
    FactoryResetTime        =       1   # [Default: 1 ] ???
    PacketSize              = 1048576   # [Default: 1048576 ] ???

    OptionEnable            =       1   # [Default: 1 ] 'Options' gets available 
    PhoneEnable             =       1   # [Default: 0 ] 'Phone EFS Clear' & 'Phone Bootloader Update' gets available
    DeviceInfo              =       1   # [Default: 0 ] 'DeviceInfo' gets available 
    RtnForSprint            =       1   # [Default: 0 ] 'RTN For Sprint' gets available

    ; Check for Update
    ;   ftp://odindown.user:nwodnido110110@165.213.149.206/pub/Tools/USB_Downloader/Odin_Downloader/
    ;   "OdinVersion.txt", "OdinNew.exe", "OdinLauncher.exe"
    ;SLP                    =       0   # Version 3.09 only! [Default: 0 ]
    ;ComPortWaitingTime     =       0   # Version 3.09 only! [Default: 1 ] 
    ;AuthorityKey           =       pw

[ButtonOption]
    Bootloader  =   1   # [Default: 1 ]     'BL'  FileInput gets available
    PDA         =   1   # [Default: 1 ]     'AP'  FileInput gets available
    Phone       =   1   # [Default: 1 ]     'CP'  FileInput gets available
    CSC         =   1   # [Default: 1 ]     'CSC' FileInput gets available
    UMS/PATCH   =   1   # [Default: 1 ]     'UMS' FileInput gets available
    ;USERDATA   =   0


[APOption]
    RePartition     =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Re-Partition'
    AutoReboot      =   0   # [Default: 1 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Auto Reboot'     Reboot after data upload
    FResetTime      =   0   # [Default: 1 ] Sets checkbox default for 'F. Reset Time'

    FlashLock       =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Flash Lock'
    NandErase       =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Nand Erase All'
    TFlash          =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'T Flash'

[CPOption]
    PhoneEFSClear   =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Phone EFS Clear'
    PhoneBootUpdate =   0   # [Default: 0 ] Sets checkbox default for 'Phone Bootloader Update'

;[UIOption]
;   LED =   0 [Default: 0 ]  Version 3.09 only! Sets checkbox default for 'LED Control'

;Note:  checkboxes for 'RTN For Sprint' & 'DeviceInfo' is missing


[D300Jig]
    ;[0] not use *DefaultValue* / COM [1~2] usable
    D300COM     =   0

    ;[0] not use *DefaultValue* / [1] use (only applied if D300COM = 1)
    MicroCable  =   0

; [PortArrange]
    ; ;SAMSUNG Mobile Modem port (for Download mode)
    ; DPort0    =   
    ; DPort1    =    
    ; DPort2    =   
    ; DPort3    =    
    ; DPort4    =    
    ; DPort5    =   
    ; DPort6    =   
    ; DPort7    =   
    ; ;SAMSUNG Android USB Modem port (for Samsung Kies)
    ; SPort0    =   
    ; SPort1    =   
    ; SPort2    =   
    ; SPort3    =   
    ; SPort4    =   
    ; SPort5    =   
    ; SPort6    =   
    ; SPort7    =
```

*Odin3.ini Api monitor log:*

```
"Option"        "Title"             "[Android + SLP]"
"Option"        "Title"             "Odin3. [Android + SLP]"
"Option"        "FactoryResetTime"  "1"
"Option"        "PacketSize"        "1048576"

"APOption"      "RePartition"       "0"
"APOption"      "AutoReboot"        "1"
"APOption"      "FResetTime"        "1"

"CPOption"      "PhoneEFSClear"     "0"
"CPOption"      "PhoneBootUpdate"   "0"

"APOption"      "FlashLock"         "0"
"APOption"      "NandErase"         "0"
"APOption"      "TFlash"            "0"

"ButtonOption"  "Bootloader"        "1"
"ButtonOption"  "PDA"               "1"
"ButtonOption"  "Phone"             "1"
"ButtonOption"  "CSC"               "1"
"ButtonOption"  "UMS/PATCH"         "1"

"Option"        "OptionEnable"      "1"
"Option"        "PhoneEnable"       "0"
"Option"        "DeviceInfo"        "0"
"Option"        "RtnForSprint"      "0"
```

I slowly try to find out more about the meaning of the options.

Some other good to know stuff:

**Odin3 keyboard shortcuts**

```
<ALT> + S           BL
<ALT> + P           AP
<ALT> + M           CP
<ALT> + C           CSC

<CTRL> + S      Start
<CTRL> + R      Reset
<CTRL> + E      Exit
```

**How Odin3 detects if some device is connected?**
    Check the *names* of the entries in
        HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
    contains '*mdm*'
    and if it's *value* starts with 'COM'

Sample

```
"\Device\ssudmdm0000"   "COM8"
```

Note: "Odin_Multi_Downloader_v4.44"(2011) is more picky and only finds 
            "\Device\sscdmdm0..9"

"Odin3.09"(2013) finds
            "\Device\ssudmdm"
            "\Device\sscdmdm"
            "\Device\ssacmdm"
            "\Device\ssadmdm"

It's 'SAMSUNG Mobile USB Modem'(USB\VID_04E8&PID_685D&Modem) 
that writes the entries to 'HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM'
    -> Enabling/Disabling this in the Windows device manager triggers the
    to log entries  "Removed!! / Added!!" in Odin3

But instead of the modem disable/enable 'SAMSUNG Mobile USB CDC Composite Device' for proper reinitialisation. Or get [Nirsoft DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) and do it by this cmd-script:

```
::Comment in incase Odin3 'hangs' on  "SetupConnection.."
::  ... and so keeps an open handle to "\\Device\ssudmdm0000"
::  ... that prevents/lock the device and dependencies from being removed 
::taskkill /fi "IMAGENAME eq odin*"

DevManView /ShowLegacyDrivers  /use_wildcard /disable  "SAMSUNG Mobile USB *" 
DevManView /ShowLegacyDrivers  /use_wildcard /enable   "SAMSUNG Mobile USB *"
```

then just create a link to the desktop and set in the link properties a hot key combo
like ALT+CTRL+Y to run it.

Well alternatively so can also do it the plug'n'play way, pull the USB plug and them plug it in again.

Comment: +1 for your interest in this topic, and for the useful info you uncovered.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that The D300JIG is meant to be used with Samsungs proprietary JTAG unit called the Samsung Anyway Jig. Its what their software engineers and service centers use to revive bricked phones and flash firmware.
Either that or it could be related to flashing and servicing their D300 series smart TV's

Also Authority Key=pw is probably for a password needed to access Samsung secure servers on the ip address you mentioned above

Comment: Do you have any research to backup your claims with?