# Odin3 Bootloader button is greyed out

Tags: bootloader, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-4, baseband

I'm trying to install the custom [Rapture ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-tmobile/development/moving-please-post-t2918248) to improve performance on my aging Note 4. I've rooted it and now in following [the instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60421596&postcount=2165) I see I need to update my FW which involves loading `BASEBAND.TAR.MD5` using Odin3. ([quick link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56832475&postcount=9)).

My problem is that even though I've downloaded the baseband and bootloader when I run Odin3 all of the buttons except for 'AP' are greyed out so I cannot proceed. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: You may want to refer to my research concerning ODIN, which you can find at http://android.stackexchange.com/q/139675/152843 . Specifically, search for the **[ButtonOption]** section of my answer, and edit your **Odin3.ini** accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

In the case you weren't eager to look at the research, here's the solution.

In the same folder of your Odin executable, you'll find a file called **Odin3.ini**. Being it a configuration file, it defines the behaviour Odin should meet at startup. What we're interested into, though, is to examine its content, so fire up your text editor of choice and open the file.

Once opened, you'll see various sections, each marked by a **[Something]** label. What you need to do, is to find the **`[ButtonOption]`** label.

After you've found it, you'll see various entries under it. Specifically for your case, the section should be similar to the following:

```
[ButtonOption]
Bootloader=0
PDA=1
Phone=0
CSC=0
UMS/PATCH=0
USERDATA=0
```

Now, a **`0`** means that the corresponding checkbox is greyed out, while a **`1`** lets Odin know that such checkbox will be selectable. Since the flags' names can be confusing, here's a brief overview of their meaning:

- `Bootloader` = **BL button**
- `PDA` = **AP button**
- `Phone` = **CP button**
- `CSC` = **CSC button**
- `UMS/PATCH` = **UMS button**
- `USERDATA` = **not implemented yet**

You should now be able to edit the flags in order to activate the needed checkboxes. Just remember to save your changes afterwards.